# How to change a value in an array via a hash?

Tags: ruby

I want to change the value of an array via a hash, for example:

```
arr = ['g','g','e','z']
positions = {1 => arr[0], 2 => arr[1]}

positions[1] = "ee"
```

Problem is that the one that changed is hash and not array. When I do `p arr` It still outputs `['g','g','e','z']`. Is there a way around this?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: @MarkoAvlijaš its in the title. I want to change an array via a hash. But when I do it, the one that changes is the hash itself, not the array

Comment: @chaosfirebit and why do you want to do that?

Comment: Whenever you give an example you should include your desired result, which here is a modified `arr`. That's what @MarkoAvlijaš wants to know. Your reply merely restates what you've already said.

Answer (score 2):

You're going to need to add another line of code to do what you want:

```
arr = ['g','g','e','z']
positions = {1 => arr[0], 2 => arr[1]}

positions[1] = "ee"
arr[0] = positions[1]
```

Another option would be to make a method that automatically updated the array for you, something like this:

```
def update_hash_and_array(hash, array, val, index)
    # Assume that index is not zero indexed like you have
    hash[index] = val
    array[index - 1] = val
end

update_hash_and_array(positions, arr, "ee", 1) # Does what you want
```

Answer (score 2):

This is possible to code into your hash using procs.

```
arr = ['g','g','e','z']

positions = {1 => -> (val) { arr[0] = val } }


positions[1].('hello')
# arr => ['hello', 'g', 'e', 'z']
```

You can generalize this a bit if you want to generate a hash that can modify any array.

```
def remap_arr(arr, idx)
  (idx...arr.length+idx).zip(arr.map.with_index{|_,i| -> (val) {arr[i] = val}}).to_h
end

arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
positions = remap_arr(arr, 1)

positions[2].('hello')
# arr => [1,'hello',3,4,5,6]

positions[6].('goodbye')
# arr => [1,'hello',3,4,5,'goodbye']
```

But I'm hoping this is just a thought experiment, there is no reason to change the way array indexing behavior works to start from 1 rather than 0. In such cases, you would normally just want to offset the index you have to match the proper array indexing (starting at zero). If that is not sufficient, it's a sign you need a different data structure.

Comment: This is really interesting. I had no idea that this existed.

Comment: @gr1zzlybe4r heh, it's not really a common ruby paradigm as far as I know ... It's much more javascript-y. Like I said, there is no real reason to do this kind of thing in practice, and even then just writing a method is much clearer (as in your answer)

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

a = %w(q w e)

h = {
  1 => a[0]
}

puts a[0].object_id # 70114787518660
puts h[1].object_id # 70114787518660
puts a[0] === h[1]  # true

# It is a NEW object of a string. Look at their object_ids.
# That why you can not change value in an array via a hash.
h[1] = 'Z'

puts a[0].object_id # 70114787518660
puts h[1].object_id # 70114574058580
puts a[0] === h[1]  # false

h[2] = a

puts a.object_id    # 70308472111520
puts h[2].object_id # 70308472111520
puts h[2] === a     # true

puts a[0] === h[2][0] # true
# Here we can change value in the array via the hash.
# Why?
# Because 'h[2]' and 'a' are associated with the same object '%w(q w e)'.
# We will change the VALUE without creating a new object.
h[2][0] = 'X'

puts a[0]             # X
puts h[2][0]          # X
puts a[0] === h[2][0] # true
```